# How to combine items from a for loop into one array (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop loop like so:

This converts an array of objects into a list of objects with defined keys.

```
    this.arrayOfAllCountsSeparatedIntoObjects.map(item => {
    let objectForAnimals = {};
    let i = 1;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      objectForAnimals.category = key;
      objectForAnimals["series_" + i++] = value;
      console.log(objectForAnimals);
    }
    return objectForCharts;
  });
```

As suggested I've attempted to create an empty array and push to it as above: arrayOfItemsForCharts.push(objectForAnimals); however I think I might be writing it wrongly?

```
    this.arrayOfAllCountsSeparatedIntoObjects.map(item => {
    let objectForAnimals = {};
    var arrayOfItemsForCharts = [];
    let i = 1;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      objectForAnimals.category = key;
      objectForAnimals["series_" + i++] = value;
      newEmptyArray.push(objectForAnimals)
      console.log(objectForAnimals);
    }
    return objectForCharts;
  });
```

This puts all items in an array however it puts each individual object into an array.

The this.arrayOfAllCountsSeparatedIntoObjects looks like so in the console:

[image]

And console.log(objectForAnimals) returns the following:

[image]

(I understand that a picture often times isn't helpful, however I'm not sure how to describe this).

How can I combine all items in the bottom picture generated through the for loop into an array?

I tried to use a forEach however it doesn't quite work for this situation as I'm unsure how to combine them.

What I'm attempting to create: [{category: "Data Gathering", series_1: 12}, {category: "Evaluation", series_1: 16}, {category: "Idea Presentation", series_1: 12}, ...]

Comment: just create an empty array before entering the loop and use push() to add items in the loop?

Comment: instead of pictures, I think it's better to give an input, desired output, and what you have tried so far

Comment: Can I ask how I would write the .push? Would it be like this? newEmptyArray.push(objectForAnimals);